Understanding the Definition of $Z=E(X|\mathcal{G})$ almost sure
I am trying to understand the following definition better:

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space, $X$ a random
variable. Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of
$\mathcal{F}$.
We say that $Z$ is a version of the conditional expectation of $X$
given $\mathcal{G}$ iff:

$E(|Z|)<\infty$
$Z$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable
for every $G \in \mathcal{G}: E[Z1_G]=E[X1_G]$.

In that case $Z=E(X|\mathcal{G})$ almost sure.

The first two conditions seem reasonable.
But the third seems odd.
As $Z$ and $E(X|\mathcal{G})$ are rv, I would have assumed the condition would be pointwise euqlity, i.e. something like
$\forall \omega \in \Omega: Z(\omega)=E(X|\mathcal{G})(\omega)$.
I know, the statement is about almost sure equality. But I can't understand why we consider the expectation.

This question is a duplicate of: Proof that conditional expectation is defined uniquely almost everywhere?.

This is a definition of what the conditional expectation of $X$ given $\mathcal{G}$ means. Your suggested alternative definition includes "$E(X|\mathcal{G})$" inside it. But until we make some definition such as this one, "$E(X|\mathcal{G})$" doesn't yet have a meaning.

@KurtG It doesn't seem to be asking the same thing as the question you link to. This question asks for intuition/explanation about why the third condition in the definition is written the way it is. The question you link to asks for a proof that such an object exists and is unique up to almost sure equality.

"I can't understand why we consider the expectation". It seems quite natural that when we are defining "conditional expectation", the definition involves expectation.

@NicholasBurbank The duplicate shows precisely why a pointwise definition is not possible. Plus you have highlighted a circular reasoning in their attempt to do so.

If $X\in L^2$, then we are going to call the orthogonal projection of $X$ onto $\mathcal G$ the conditional expectation of $X$ given $\mathcal G$, denoted $E[X\mid \mathcal G]$, in analogy with the variational representation of $E[X]$ as the minimizer of $c\mapsto E|c-X|^2$. By definition $X-E[X\mid \mathcal G]$ lies in the orthogonal complement of $\mathcal G$, which is what the condition $E[X\mathbf 1_B] = E[E[X\mid \mathcal G]\mathbf 1_B]$ means for $B\in \mathcal G$. Conversely, if $Z$ satisfies such a condition, then $Z$ is necessarily the orthogonal projection of $X$ onto $\mathcal G$.
There is no notion of orthogonal projection for $L^1$, but one can lift this definition to $L^1$ random variables by requiring this "orthogonality condition."

There is more than one r.v. satisfying the definiition above, in general. However, any two $Z$  satisfying it, will be a.s. equal. So th conditional expectation is defined uniquely upto sets of measure zero.
